# navigationBar display deranged

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I create a subclass of UINavigationController, like this

```
@interface CustomNav : UINavigationController
@property(assign , nonatomic) BOOL canBack;
@end 

@implementation CustomNav
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.canBack = YES;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    id target = self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate;
    UIPanGestureRecognizer * pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] 
initWithTarget:target action:@selector(handleNavigationTransition:)];
    pan.delegate = self;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pan];
    self.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
}

-(BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
//    NSLog(@"self.childViewControllers.count = %li",self.childViewControllers.count);
    if (self.childViewControllers.count==1||!self.canBack) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
@end
```

but when i use it to push viewController , the navigationBar display deranged ,for example, it has A viewController, then it push another B viewController,but sometimes, it doesn't display the navigationItem of B , it just display the navigationItem of A , and then I push C to the CustomNav , it also display the navigationItem of A. i don't know why ,i found it seems the  CustomNav display the navigationItem of B(or C) ，and then the navigationBar covered by the navigationItem of A . Could everyOne help  me ?   Thank you ever so much.

Comment: What does your `handleNavigationTransition:` method do?

Comment: i don't  overwrite any method of  superClass(UINavigationController)  , so   the  handleNavigationTransition: method   run as  superClass method , should I do something in the method?  in addition ， i didn't  use the handleNavigationTransition: method  before.

Comment: the navigationBar display deranged happen sometime , but the frequency is not high. i have no idea about the problem .